# Remove animation when loading webpage

Tags: html, css, animation

On most browser-os-constillations the standard background of the site is white, so if I create a website I at first set the background-color to something dark. But if I try and set the transition property on "*", the background also fades in, which, in my opinion, looks bad. How can I remove that?

```css
*{
  transition: 2s;
}
body{
  background-color: #000
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you heard of the css pseudo selector `:not`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 3):

if your point is to select all and avoid the body from transition

you can use `:not(body)` :

```
:not(body){
  transition: 2s;
}
body{
  background-color: #000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to be able to replicate the fade transition of the background you're describing.

However, if you need to exclude a specific element and/or property from animating, you can do it like this:

- To exclude an element:

  ```css
  *:not(body) {
    transition: all 2s;
  }
  ```
- To exclude a property:

  ```css
  * {
    transition: all 2s, background-color 0;
  }
  ```

Or to prevent the transitioning of `background-color` on the `body`:

```css
* {
  transition: all 2s;
}

body {
  transition: all 2s, background-color 0;
}
```